# how to implement rest client with gluon plugin

Tags: rest, gluon

I am following the gluon rest sample to access to a rest server. But I get nothing from the server. the object is null. so what is wrong with the code. The object is there and reachable by http.

```
  RestClient restClient = RestClient.create()
        .method("GET")
        .host("https://storage.waw.cloud.ovh.net")
        .path("/v1/AUTH_17fd5ed14d1440b0abc4918f6a492bd9/dataCours/pourShema.json")

           .contentType("charset=utf-8");
        InputStreamInputConverter<CoursFrancaisJson> converter = new JsonInputConverter<>(CoursFrancaisJson.class);     
 GluonObservableObject<CoursFrancaisJson> retrieveObject = DataProvider.retrieveObject(restClient.createObjectDataReader(converter));
```

Comment: I've just tested without your converter (`GluonObservableObject<String>...createObjectDataReader(String.class));`, and that works fine. Make sure the `CoursFrancaisJson` contains the right fields (`List<Page> page` and `String lang`...)

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
I tried with a simple object and still not working. I do something wrong but can find it